# Popping first element from a Python tuple

Tags: python

Is there any way to pop the first element from a Python tuple?

For example, for

```
tuple('A', 'B', 'C')
```

I would like to pop off the 'A' and have a tuple containing 'B' and 'C'.

Since tuples are immutable I understand that I need to copy them to a new tuple. But how can I filter out only the first element of the tuple?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With this tuple

```
x = ('A','B','C')
```

you can get a tuple containing all but the first element using a slice:

```
x[1:]
```

Result:

```
('B','C')
```